# ASP.NET Identity UserStore: Why return Task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have wondered about this for a while now, all `UserStore` methods return a `Task` or a typed `Task<T>`, but why do they? Why not just return T?
I understand that they are Aync methods and are part of OWIN middleware, does that have something to do with it?

I also notice that some methods that return a plain old `Task` actually return an empty `Task`.
The samples of the asp.net website return `Task.FromResult<object>(null)` http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity.
I have also seen `Task.FromResult(0)`, and if I return a Task with a `Action`:

```
return new Task(() =>
{
    context.User.Add(new User); context.SaveChanges()
})
```

Then the `Action` inside the `Task` is not invoked. Why is this and what is the point of returning an empty `Task`? It seems to me that returning a `Task` is akin to a `void` method, is that correct?

Comment: No. The Task class is found in the System.Threading.Tasks namespace and is used when introducing parallelism into your applications. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I really would recommend your read [MSDN / Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/hh191443.aspx) which is really helpful to get an understanding of HOW all of the async/await works (behind the curtains).

The reason why those techniques are actually used is that the UserManager implementations usually imply working against a database, which is "slow" in Computer time (great reading from Jeff Atwood on that topic: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/).

For that reason the UserManager methods give you the promise to provide you with `TypeX` or `ResultY` in the future, but it will take *time*. In order to liberate resources while your application is waiting for the DB to answer (as an example) the waiting thread <strike>is put to sleep</strike> be returned to the ThreadPool, and that liberated capacity could be used for yet another incomming request (or whatever task that might have completed asynchronously during that time).

Edit: thank you @Neil Hibbert

Comment: Hmm I would describe the working Thread as being returned to the ThreadPool rather than being put to sleep. C# automatically converts methods using async/await into a state machine and is able to block execution of a method until the awaited task completes...

Answer (score 3):

According to  MSDN / Asynchronous Programming documentation:

> Asynchrony is essential for activities that are potentially blocking,
>   such as when your application accesses the web. Access to a web
>   resource sometimes is slow or delayed. If such an activity is blocked
>   within a synchronous process, the entire application must wait. In an
>   asynchronous process, the application can continue with other work
>   that doesn't depend on the web resource until the potentially blocking
>   task finishes.

Database call (specially in cloud environments like Microsoft Azure and others) is blocking I/O process and for this reason most of the APIs in the ASP.NET Identity system are asynchronous.

And why empty `Task` ? returning empty `Task` is a best practice in `Async/Await Programming` model. There are three possible return types for async methods: `Task`, `Task<T>`; and `void`, but the natural return types for async methods are just `Task` and `Task<T>`. When converting from synchronous to asynchronous code, any method returning a type `T` becomes an async method returning `Task<T>`, and any method returning `void` becomes an async method returning `Task`.

- Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an
  exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task<T> method,
  that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async
  void methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out
  of an async void method will be raised directly on the
  SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method
  started.
- Async void methods have different composing semantics. Async methods
  returning Task or Task<T> can be easily composed using await,
  Task.WhenAny, Task.WhenAll and so on. Async methods returning void
  don’t provide an easy way to notify the calling code that they’ve
  completed. It’s easy to start several async void methods, but it’s
  not easy to determine when they’ve finished. Async void methods will
  notify their SynchronizationContext when they start and finish, but a
  custom SynchronizationContext is a complex solution for regular
  application code.
- Async void methods are difficult to test. Because of the differences
  in error handling and composing, it’s difficult to write unit tests
  that call async void methods. The MSTest asynchronous testing support
  only works for async methods returning Task or Task<T>. It’s possible
  to install a SynchronizationContext that detects when all async void
  methods have completed and collects any exceptions, but it’s much
  easier to just make the async void methods return Task instead.

You should prefer `async Task` to `async void`. `Async Task` methods enable easier error-handling, composability and testability. For more information read this article: [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)